# VSO Board - is it possible to see bugs/tasks items assigned to "John" but user story is assigned to "Paul"?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using VSO in our organization
Currently, user John - can see on his board -  all the user stories assigned to him.

[image]

However, we have 2 problems :

1. Not all bugs are assigned to a user story, and hence I don't see them in John's board, even if they are assigned to John
2. If Paul has a user story assigned to him , but has a bug ( under his user story), assigned to John, I can't see it in John's board

**Question**

How can I see items on the board by the assigned name ( regardless of the attached user story) ? For example All items being assigned to John ( even if User story is on Paul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to decide where you want to see your bugs (with tasks or with stories): [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops)
2. Then you can filter items on boards... the filter applies only to the topic items:

   1. if you are on the sprint board: tasks (and bugs by default)
   2. if you are on the backlog board: stories (and bugs if configured), but not for child items.

To get a more flexible list of work items, try to use the work item queries: [Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks , If I understand you correctly , there is no way to see in the board , a bug that I'm currently working on , and the user story assigned to someone else ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I do not see any bug on the story level on your screenshot.... In this case, you have to go to the sprint board then you will see your bug and parent story (assigned to anyone). To see bugs and stories together on one board, you have to use `Bugs are managed with requirements`. In this case, you may use the board filter `@Me + (Someone else)`.

Comment: Here is the full scenario : https://i.imgur.com/F1tOJPA.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir In your case, you are using `Bugs are managed with tasks` where it is not possible to see a bug (as a separate ticket) on the backlog level (or boards section).